# Reactjs Firebase User Authentication Protected Routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Im using firebase `user authentication` service with `reactjs`. I'm having a problem with `auth.onAuthStateChanged` function firing after the component has been rendered. Im using `protected` routes and passing prop to it. This creates a problem redirecting the user to specific page.

Ex: `domain.com/signin` page should redirect user to `domain.com/customers` once user is authenticated. Currently is just taking to domain.com and when user logout it should redirect to `domain.com/signin`.

code:https://codesandbox.io/s/serverless-leaf-pgtf1?fontsize=14

I tried this code

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
    if (user && user.emailVerified) {
       this.setState({
         authenticated: true
      });
    } else {
       this.setState({
         authenticated: false
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: Just to clarify, you want users to be redirected to a specific page after login yeah?

Comment: Yes, Once user is signed in and authenticated it will be redirect it to domain.com/customers. All component are already set up for some reason is no working. No sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UnauthorizedRoute` high order component is set up such that when users are not authenticated, it redirects them straight to the home page i.e `domain.com/`.

```
const UnauthorizedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  authenticated,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authenticated === false ? (
          <Component {...props} {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

What you can do to be able to redirect users to specific page after they are authenticated is to add an extra props to the `UnauthorizedRoute` component, for example, `afterAuthPath`, if this prop is available, the `UnauthorizedRoute` component would redirect users to the `afterAuthPath` path if they are authenticated otherwise it would use the default behavior of redirecting to the home page. The implementation can be like this:

```
const UnauthorizedRoute = ({
  component: Component,
  authenticated,
  afterAuthPath,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const redirectPath = afterAuthPath || "/";
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={props =>
        authenticated === false ? (
          <Component {...props} {...rest} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to={redirectPath} />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

You can then do this for the sign in and any other route that requires such behavior:

```
<UnauthorizedRoute
  authenticated={props.authenticated}
  path="/signin"
  afterAuthPath="/customers"
  component={SignInCustomer}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. That works. Can you please explain a little bit more. Im no 100% sure why this method of passing another props works. If you can tell me more I'll appreciate it